# Model State always true in asp.Net Core web Api 2.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When I am using .net Core version 2.1.0 and for Model State Validation using below code is just work fine.

In **Startup.cs** file add below code

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());
});
```

and Create **ValidateModelAttribute** like this

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

but now I am using `2.1.1` and i try all `google and SO post but Model State is always true`.

even i am sending empty json object.

In the documentation it is say that in 2.1.1 the Model State error is automatically handle by the `ApiController` but still it is not given proper result. and i am also add `[Required]` on property but in all case it is value and go to next step.

If someone require any additional information then comment. i will add other information too.

Comment: You could post your model in question and the signature of the method called. You're aware that model binding only works when the model is passed as class yes? `public IActionResult Update([FromBody]MyModel abc)` (`[FromBody]` only required pre-ASP.NET Core w/o ApiController attribute), when you have *exactly* one model in the methods parameters

Answer (score 1):

> In the documentation it is say that in 2.1.1 the Model State error is automatically handle by the ApiController but still it is not given proper result. and i am also add [Required] on property but in all case it is value and go to next step.

When you use ASP.NET Core 2.1 (or 2.2 for that matter), then the **new features**  with changed behavior (such as `[ApiController]`) are opt-in.

The automatic model validation with the `[ApiController]` Attribute only works when you opt-in to the ASP.NET Core 2.1 (or 2.2 if you are on ASP.NET Core 2.2) features.

You can do that in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
```

This will enable the automatic validation with the `[ApiController]` attribute. This is also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute).

> A compatibility version of 2.1 or later, set via `SetCompatibilityVersion`, is required to use this attribute. For example, the highlighted code in `Startup.ConfigureServices`  sets the 2.2 compatibility flag:
>
> ```
> services.AddMvc()
>    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
>    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
>    {
>        options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
>        options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
>        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
>        options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
>
>        options.ClientErrorMapping[404] = "https://httpstatuses.com/404";
>    });
> ```

Also see the [ASP.NET Core 2.1-preview1 Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/introducing-compatibility-version-in-mvc/).